# If $P(X_n\ne0\ \text{i.o.})=1$ then $P(c_n|X_n|>1\ \text{i.o.})=1$ for some suitable sequence $(c_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, almost-everywhere

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be random variables such that $P\{X_n  \neq 0 \text{ i.o}\} = 1$. From this it follows that $P\{\sum_{k \leq n} |X_k| > 0\} \rightarrow 1$. Show that there exists constants $c_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P\{|c_nX_n|  > 1 \text{ i.o}\}=1$.

This seems intuitively clear. Since the $\sum_{k \leq n} |X_k| > 0$ almost everywhere for sufficiently large $n$, it seems like I can find the infimum $\alpha_n = \inf\{X_n(\omega): \sum_{k \leq n} |X_k(\omega)| > 0\}$. Then taking $c_n = 1/\alpha_n$, the value $|c_nX_n| > 1$ almost surely.

Is this the right track? How do I formalize this into a proof?

Comment: A hint maybe...?

Comment: Your attempt is doomed since these $\alpha_n$ are random. Here is an explicit, albeit slightly tedious, approach. Define $S_n=|X_1|+\cdots+|X_n|$ for every $n$ and fix some sequence $(u_k)$ in $(0,1/2)$. Choose $n_1$ such that $P(S_{n_1}>0)\geqslant1-u_1$, then some $x_1>0$ such that $P(S_{n_1}>x_1)\geqslant1-2u_1$. Now restart with $(X_k)_{k\gt n_1}$ and the probability $u_2$ to construct $n_2$ and $x_2$ such that $P(S_{n_2}-S_{n_1}>x_2)\geqslant1-2u_2$. And so on. This yelds $(n_k)$ and $(x_k)$ such that $P(S_{n_k}-S_{n_{k-1}}>x_k)\geqslant1-2u_k$ for every $k$. ...

Comment: ... If the series $\sum\limits_ku_k$ converges, by Borel-Cantelli, $S_{n_k}-S_{n_{k-1}}>x_k$ infinitely often, almost surely. Finally, for every $k$ and every $i$ in $[n_{k-1}+1,n_k]$, define $$c_i=\frac{n_k-n_{k-1}}{x_k},$$ and note that $$[S_{n_k}-S_{n_{k-1}}>x_k]\subseteq[\exists i\in[n_{k-1}+1,n_k],c_i|X_i|>1].$$

Comment: What is the source of this exercise?

Comment: @zhoraster No, both statements very much involve the joint distribution of the sequence $(X_n)$ hence one cannot assume independence.

Comment: @Did, right you are.